# AttributeError: module 'MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE' has no attribute 'JSON' while migrating in Django

Tags: python, django, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I do not know in what way solve this error. Any hints? I have simple Django projects and receive this error when try to do python3 manage.py migrate. This is related to any programming error in app or this is possible there is any error related to installation of mysql and completeness of its packages? Maybe there is any error in manage.py file? Or maybe this is case in not compatible version of Django and mysql?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",      
line 401, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",    
line 377, in execute
django.setup()
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in     
populate
app_config.import_models()
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in   
import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2,   
in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 
48, in <module>
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in 
__new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in 
add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 206, 
in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in 
__getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 214, in 
__getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in 
load_backend
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 
29, in <module>
from .introspection import DatabaseIntrospection            # isort:skip
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-
packages/django/db/backends/mysql/introspection.py", line 16, in <module>
class DatabaseIntrospection(BaseDatabaseIntrospection):
File "/home/anna/.local/lib/python3.7/site-   
packages/django/db/backends/mysql/introspection.py", line 27, in DatabaseIntrospection
FIELD_TYPE.JSON: 'JSONField',
AttributeError: module 'MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE' has no attribute 'JSON'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 16):

```
pip install mysqlclient==2.0.1
```

You need to update mysqlclient, version 2.0.1 is the current version and it solves this missing definition.

Comment: Your answer was helpful but it just answered what to solve not how to solve

Comment: How to solve it, update mysqlclient to at least 2.0.1. pip install mysqclient==2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error and I realised later that I wasn't running my code in virtual environment. Maybe you forgot to activate virtual environment.

Comment: Guess what, pycharm didn't activate the virtualenv automatically and I faced this.