# Django connect to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

```
 DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': 'onlineCourse',
       'HOST': 'localhost',
       'PORT': '3306',
       'USER': 'root',
       'PASSWORD': 'root',
   }
```

}

**I tried to connect mysql to django follow django tutorial but its not work when i press in commnadline python manage.py migrate so it report error like below. someone help me please**
FIELD_TYPE.JSON: 'JSONField',
AttributeError: module 'MySQLdb.constants.FIELD_TYPE' has no attribute 'JSON'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the Postgres JSON field:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
```

Or if this is a new app this might be related to the MySQL version as suggested in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63525904/attributeerror-module-mysqldb-constants-field-type-has-no-attribute-json-wh)

Comment: thank you. I added  Postgres JSON field in my code but its still not work and the link that you give me contain exactly my bug. I unknow  how check mysqlclient version I just install its by anaconda severall day so I think its latest version.

Comment: oh thank you so much i just install mysqlclient version 2.0.1 by pip and its working.